# Modify Azure AD User Account through HashiCorp's Vault?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, credentials, hashicorp-vault

Looking through documentations got a bit overwhelming so I am going to ask the question here.

What I have:
1. Existing **Azure AD account** with elevated priviliges
2. Existing **Azure AD account** I want to be able to modify(username + password are the only important things I need)
What I want to do:
1. **Retrieve existing account credentials** through **HashiCorp's Vault**(username + password)
2. **Change existing account password** through **HashiCorp's Vault**
Question:
Is that possible through **HashiCorp's Vault** using the **elevated Azure AD account**? If yes, could you please point me to the correct Vault + Azure(if needed) documentation? If that is possible only through **Azure APIs**, could you point me to that documentation?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with azure AD, im assuming its behaving as a normal AD.

You can use the [active directory secrets engine](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/ad/)

Its not using the Azure API, its using a golang library to talk LDAP/AD to the AD: 
* https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-plugin-secrets-ad/blob/7a2d5ec6d30d7dac26859dedefbf92938a4877ff/plugin/client/client.go#L59
* https://github.com/go-ldap/ldap/tree/master/v3

If you need the Azure API, you'll need to develop your own vault plugin unfortunately.